# My calculated member is not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datasource, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I tried to create a calculated member for displaying profit for each product, but I got an error on the "select". Can anyone help me out with this since I am newbie in this?

```sql
CALCULATE;  
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].Profit_Per_Produkt
 AS Select [Measures].[Vinst] on columns,
[Dim Produkt].[Artikelnr].[Artikelnr] on rows
from [Elektronikkedja], 
FORMAT_STRING = "Percent", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Fact Köp' ;
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a calculated _member_ that isn't a member but a 2D slice of the cube.  A member must be an expression that yields a single value.

Answer (score 0):

A calculated member you should contains a calculate expression as:

```
([Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount] - 
[Measures].[Internet Sales-Total Product Cost]) /
[Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount]
```

See on [technet Defining Calculated docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166568.aspx) a some samples.